# How do I compile bitcoin-qt 0.13 for Windows 10 and use gdb (or similar) to debug it?

Tags: bitcoind, windows

Currently I'm working on a fork from 0.13, so apologies if this is documented in later version.

I'm cross-compiling bitocin-qt for Windows 10 (following the instructions in the build-windows document), although technically I would consider running an X11 version instead. My preference is to compile the Windows native version and be able to use gdb in the same way that I can do under Linux.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Can you list which platform(s) (1) you're building on (2) you're building for/running on and (3) you're debugging on.

Comment: Peter, I'm using the standard build method as detailed in the build-windows document in the docs directory.

Comment: But on what platform? Are you building on windows, or on linux? And do you want to run gdb while in windows or in linux?

Comment: I'm compiling on Windows 10 using WSL. I'd like to use any free debugger, but preferably gdb. Currently compiling with --enable-debug seems to cause errors though.